# how do we check if an element in the array exists and if it has a value of "true" in Presto

Tags: sql, arrays, where-clause, presto

The data in the array looks like XXXX:"False". I used

`element_at(array_name,'Field') and contains(map_keys(array_name),'Field')`. They only check if the element is present in the array. But if the 'Field' has a value of 'true', How do i check that value?

Comment: What is the exact type of `array_name`? (what does `SELECT DISTINCT typeof(array_name) ...` return?)

Comment: I might be wrong in explaining, but the distinct query retuerned "map(varchar, varchar)", i think array_name above is the map and 'Field is the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a map at hand, and that you want to check the value of of a given key, you can just use `element_at()`:

```
where element_at(array_name, 'Field') = 'True'
```