# Athena query failing with field not present

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have S3 data files in JSON format and after running a glue crawler the data is available in Athena tables.

In the Athena table I have a column(say attributes) with type `<struct<x:string>,<y: int>,etc.>`. Now, after some cut-off date, a new field (say `z`) is added in this attributes column and now the data type is `<struct<x:string>,<y: int>,<z:String> , <etc.>>`.

**Requirement**

I want to query both the old data and new data with the same query which filters on the basis of values of `z`.

**Issue**

The issue is previous data does not contain this field and when I apply the `where` clause, it gives error as the field is not found in old data. Is there an option to not fail the query on old data or consider the absent field in attribute as null?

Comment: Might help: [sql - how do we check if an element in the array exists and if it has a value of "true" in Presto - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587220/how-do-we-check-if-an-element-in-the-array-exists-and-if-it-has-a-value-of-true)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`COALESCE()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#coalesce) to insert a default value for `z`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT col.x, col.y, COALESCE(col.z, 0)
FROM table
WHERE COALESCE(col.z, 0) > 0;
```